# ReactJS | Typescript type for onClick. `onclick does not exist on type`x`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, onclick

I have the below method, that renders a delete Icon, and I use it in my main Container. Everything works fine. The only problem, I have, and it is a small cosmetic one, is an `any` type that I cannot figure out, what that type is.

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from './Icon';

const DeleteActionRenderer = (options: any): Function => (cell: string, row: string): JSX.Element => {
  const deleteActionClick = options.onClick({ cell, row }); // The error is here. On options.onClick.
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#" className="text-danger p-1 text-lg" onClick={deleteActionClick}>
        <Icon icon="trash" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DeleteActionRenderer;
```

As you can see, `options` have `any` as a type. I cannot figure out, what options is. Nothing except any works. `object, string, number, Function, MouseEvents, SyntheticEvent`. Not even `unknown`.

The only type that works is `any`.

I console.log(options, typeOf options), and it prints out an object. See below:

```
{onClick: ƒ}
onClick: ƒ (_ref2)
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: index.tsx:146
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[5]
__proto__: Object
```

Any ideas? This `any` is like a sore thumb, for a little while now. I cannot figure it out at all. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above looks to me like a HOC (High Order Component) https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

I can see in your code that the way you are using `DeleteActionRenderer` is not correct as the `options` object in this case is part of props so it will be coming in the function that you return from `DeleteActionRenderer` and not in `DeleteActionRenderer` itself.

In your case, for `options` type will be:

```
type Options = {
   onClick: Function
}
```

Hope it helps.